# Make editable PDF readonly from stream

Tags: c#, file, pdf

I have a **Stream** object of a PDF file. The file is editable. I would like to make the file read only. How do I achieve this ?

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Pdf);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

ms.Position = 0;
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(ms);
writer.SetCloseStream(false);
ms.Position = 0;
var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);

PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
form.FlattenFields();
form.SetGenerateAppearance(true);

pdfDoc?.Close();

ms.Position = 0;

var fileAsBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
byte[] pdfBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(fileAsBase64);
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\ResultSamples\PdfSample.pdf", pdfBytes);

ms?.Close();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "editable" and "read only"?

Comment: editable means the pdf is fillable. readonly means not fillable.

Comment: You point the `PdfWriter` to your stream with the source pdf. But a `PdfWriter` *writes*, it doesn't *read*. Thus, your original file gets overridden. You need both a `PdfReader` and a `PdfWriter`.

Answer (score 1):

```
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileAsBase64))
            {                

                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(fileAsBase64);


                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(new MemoryStream(bytes));
                pdfReader.SetUnethicalReading(true);
                MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();



                using (PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(outputStream))
                using (PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter))
                {
                    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
                    form.FlattenFields();
                    pdfDoc.Close();
                }



                fileAsBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(outputStream.ToArray());
            }
```